# How to preprocess info to match the join in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, that I would like to link by its `type` field.

**table1**

```
id | type
---+--------
1  | One
2  | Two
3  | Three
4  | Four
5  | Two
```

**table2**

```
id | type
---+------
34 | N
35 | Z
26 | Y
27 | W
```

And the equivalent table is (this table does not exist and cannot exist)

```
One = Z
Two = Y
Three = N
Four = W
```

And my query is

```
SELECT t1.type 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.type = t2.type
```

Probably the best solution will be change the information in one of the tables. But I cannot do that, I also can't create any store procedure.
I would like to have just one query to do this.

Any idea?

Comment: Is your 'equivalent' table a third table that you have access to?

Comment: @JoshuaR. The question originally said that table doesn't exist, but someone edited that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can synthesize the relationship table in the query:

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1, t1.type, t2.id AS id2
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 'One' AS `long`, 'Z' AS short
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Two', 'Y'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Three', 'N'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Four', 'W'
) AS r ON t1.type = r.long
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.type = r.short
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/845f2c/2)

Comment: `long` is a reserved word, needs to be escaped

Comment: That's because you never inserted anything into table2.

Comment: All your inserts are into table1, I fixed it in my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably the best solution will be change the information in one of the tables. But I cannot do that, I also can't create any store procedure. I would like to have just one query to do this.

You don't necessarily have to change the information in one of the two tables. You could create a table which contains the relationships between the two types, *i.e.*:

**table3**

```
type1 | type2
------+------
One   | Z
Two   | Y
Three | N
Four  | W
```

Then you could write a query like this:

```
SELECT table1.type 
FROM table1
JOIN table3
    ON table1.type = table3.type1
JOIN table2
    ON table3.type2 = table2.type
```